# Javascript generator catch error

Tags: javascript, error-handling, ecmascript-6, koa

I'm using [ES6 generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) in Javascript and trying to wrap my head around how to handle error thrown by a library I'm using. Following is the code snippet :

```
const feedParser = require('co-feedparser');
try {
    const meta = yield feedParser(url);
    return meta.articles;
} catch(e) {
    logger.error(e);
}
```

The library being used is [co-feedparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-feedparser) which is a co wrapper around feedparser library. The library works well when urls being passed have valid rss feeds. However, whenever an invalid rss url feed is passed, instead of catching the exception, the app crashes and dumps

```
/node_modules/co-feedparser/node_modules/feedparser/main.js:332
      this.stack[0][stdEl] = n;
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'feed' of false`
```

Which I believe is an exception in the feedparser library. How can I ensure that these exceptions are caught instead of crashing the entire app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem from `co-feedparser` for not doing correct error handling. Especially in creating a new request stream from the given url and pipe the stream to the `Feedparser`.

Although it is not a perfect solution. But you can catch application-wide errors in one place using the following.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err){
  console.error('uncaughtException: ' + err.message);
  console.error(err.stack);
  process.exit(1);             // exit with error
});
```

Comment: Only problem with this approach is, the app doesn't send any response if the error was thrown of because of bad request parameters